# C++ #elif directive is being discarded

Tags: c++, templates, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I am trying to create a type declaration based on boundaries

```
template<class B>
struct IntDecl {

enum {
    L = B::_l, U = B::_u
};
 #if (L >=0 && U <=255)
  typedef char Type;
 #elif (L>=0&&U<=65535) 
  typedef unsigned int Type;
 #endif

};
```

So, as you see here depending on the value of `L` and `U` the type will be defined.
for example

```
IntDecl< BOUND < 0, 65535 > >::Type i; // this should be a unsigned int 
IntDecl< BOUND < 0, 255 > >::Type i1;  // this should be a char
```

The problem is , both ( `i` and `i1`) are considered `chars`, in other words the `#elif` is being discarded. any help? why `#elif` is not executing?

Comment: You're misunderstanding. The preprocessor runs before the compiler and just does text substitution.

Comment: It's best not to use names starting with an underscore; they are largely reserved for use by 'the implementation'.  You'd also end up with a problem if U is greater than 65535 (if the construct using the C preprocessor was going to work at all).  You should have a `#else` clause so that you cover the other cases (and it might contain a `#error` directive to prevent the code compiling with a better message than you'd get from not defining `Type` at all).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes I agree, but its not working basically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preprocessor pass happens before semantic analysis and enum is a semantic construct. You need to use templates to implement this, or make `L` and `U` macros that define preprocessor constants.